# how to populate the end time in timepicker dropdown based on selected start time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to set operation hours for a business. End time should be 1hr after the start time and the endtime dropdown should not show values on/ before start time.
Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/knb586h4/2/)

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('agencyApp', [])
    .controller('HoursController', HoursController)
    .directive('timePicker', timePicker);

  function HoursController() {
var vm = this;

vm.print = function() {
  console.log(vm);
};
vm.setClosed = setClosed;
vm.setAllWeekdayClosed = setAllWeekdayClosed;
vm.weekdays = [{
  Day: 'Monday',
  fromTime: "Select",
  toTime: "Select"
}, {
  Day: 'Tuesday',
  fromTime: "Select",
  toTime: "Select"
}, {
  Day: 'Wednesday',
  fromTime: "Select",
  toTime: "Select"
}, {
  Day: 'Thursday',
  fromTime: "Select",
  toTime: "Select"
}, {
  Day: 'Friday',
  fromTime: "Select",
  toTime: "Select"
}, {
  Day: 'Saturday',
  fromTime: "closed",
  toTime: "closed"
}, {
  Day: 'Sunday',
  fromTime: "closed",
  toTime: "closed"
}];

vm.closed = [
  false, false, false, false, false, true, true
];

function setClosed(index) {
  if (vm.closed[index]) {
    vm.weekdays[index].toTime = vm.weekdays[index].fromTime = 'closed';
  }
  if (!vm.closed[index]) {
    vm.weekdays[index].fromTime = 'Select';
    vm.weekdays[index].toTime = 'Select';
  }
};

function setAllWeekdayClosed(index) {
  if (vm.closed[index]) {
    vm.weekdays[index].toTime = vm.weekdays[index].fromTime = 'closed';
  }
  if (!vm.closed[index]) {
    vm.weekdays[index].fromTime = '7:00 am';
    vm.weekdays[index].toTime = '3:00 pm';
  }
};
```

}

function timePicker() {
    var ddo = {
      template: '',
      restrict: 'E',
      require: 'ngModel',
      replace: true,
      compile: compileFn
    };
    return ddo;

```
function compileFn(tElement, tAttrs) {
  tElement.attr('ng-model', tAttrs.ngModel);
  //tElement.attr('ng-disabled', tAttrs.ngModel + ' === "closed"');
  return linkFn;
};

function linkFn(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.timings = ['Select', '12:15 am', '12:30 am', '12:45 am',
    '1:00 am', '1:15 am', '1:30 am', '1:45 am',
    '2:00 am', '2:15 am', '2:30 am', '2:45 am',
    '3:00 am', '3:15 am', '3:30 am', '3:45 am',
    '4:00 am', '4:15 am', '4:30 am', '4:45 am',
    '5:00 am', '5:15 am', '5:30 am', '5:45 am',
    '6:00 am', '6:15 am', '6:30 am', '6:45 am',
    '7:00 am', '7:15 am', '7:30 am', '7:45 am',
    '8:00 am', '8:15 am', '8:30 am', '8:45 am',
    '9:00 am', '9:15 am', '9:30 am', '9:45 am',
    '10:00 am', '10:15 am', '10:30 am', '10:45 am',
    '11:00 am', '11:15 am', '11:30 am', '11:45 am',
    '12:00 pm', '12:15 pm', '12:30 pm', '12:45 pm',
    '1:00 pm', '1:15 pm', '1:30 pm', '1:45 pm',
    '2:00 pm', '2:15 pm', '2:30 pm', '2:45 pm',
    '3:00 pm', '3:15 pm', '3:30 pm', '3:45 pm',
    '4:00 pm', '4:15 pm', '4:30 pm', '4:45 pm',
    '5:00 pm', '5:15 pm', '5:30 pm', '5:45 pm',
    '6:00 pm', '6:16 pm', '6:30 pm', '6:45 pm',
    '7:00 pm', '7:15 pm', '7:30 pm', '7:45 pm',
    'closed'
  ];
};
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have to write a custom filter to filter out time options which are before selected start time.

I have done it for you. Please refer [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knb586h4/3/)

```
angular.module('agencyApp', [])
  .controller('HoursController', HoursController)
  .directive('timePicker', timePicker)
  .filter('timeFilter', function () {
    return function (input, filterCriteria) {
      if (filterCriteria && filterCriteria !== "Select") {
        input = input || [];
        if (filterCriteria === 'closed') {
          return ['closed'];
        }
        var out = [];
        input.forEach(function (time) {
          if (moment(time, 'h:mm a').isAfter(moment(filterCriteria, 'h:mm a'))) {
            out.push(time);
          }
        });
        return out;
      } else {
        return input;
      }
    };
  })
```

I have added momentjs for time comparison.

Directive template will look like this.

```
<select class="input-small" ng-options="time as time for time in timings | timeFilter:min"></select>
```

And now directive will use `min` attribute to filter.

```
scope:{
 min: '='
}
```

**Usage**

```
<time-picker ng-model="vm.weekdays[$index].toTime" id="aid-to-{{$index}}" name="to" min="vm.weekdays[$index].fromTime"></time-picker>
```

See the `min` attribute accepting `fromTime`

Comment: Select from time 10:00 AM and to time 7:00 PM. Now change 10am to 7pm.(both from time and to time are same). To time goes blank. How to set max filter to From Time

Comment: @dragonfly  Your comments from the question 'the end time dropdown should not show values `on`/ before start time', and now you are saying it is going blank which actually right.